# Bootstrap navbar strange issue on mobile

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-2

i have a website that use bootstrap 2.1.1 and the navbar on mobile device as a bug. When i click on the drop down icon, the navbar open very fast and collapse after that. When i reclick, it open normally, but if i click on the Produits dropdown that i sinside the original one, it open ok but when i click on a link inside this dropdown it seems to click on a link inside the background where another link was before i dropdown the menu. The navbar code is as follow:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
       
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id=navbar-1>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li id="home-lnk"><a href="/">Accueil</a></li>
                    <li id="produits-lnk" role="presentation" class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Produits <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li id="system-lnk"><a href="/systeme">Système de gestion automatisé</a></li>
                            <li id="releasers-lnk"><a href="/relacheurs">Relâcheurs / Trappe à humidité / Panier Balle</a></li>
                            <li id="vacuum-lnk"><a href="/pompes_vacuum">Pompes Vacuum</a></li>
                            <li id="modulation-lnk"><a href="/controleur_modulation">Contrôleurs de modulation pour pompe vacuum</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="team-lnk"><a href="/equipe">Équipe</a></li>
                    <li id="contact-lnk"><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
                    <!--<li id="ditributors-lnk"><a href="/distributeurs">Distributeurs</a></li>-->
                    <li id="catalog-lnk"><a target="_blank" href="/files/Catalogue_ErabliTEK_2019.pdf">Catalogue (PDF)</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                    <li><a href="http://admin.erablitek.com">Connexion</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bonjour, je vais tester ça dans codepen je vous reviens.

Comment: Y a-t-il une raison particulière d'utiliser la v2.1.1?

Comment: C'est simplement car ca fait plusieurs année que c'est fait! J’espérais ne pas avoir a updater si possible.

Comment: le site est http://www.erablitek.com si tu veux tester.

Comment: aaah ok c'est un update job. je comprends mieux. je regarde ça 2 minutes je te reviens

Comment: j'ai trouvé les 2 bugs, je suis juste à créer une copie approximative de la page d'accueil pour tester ma solution et ensuite je te la publie ici devrait pas être vraiment long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the homepage HTML, line 22:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/require.js" data-main="/js/common.js"></script>
```

Inside common.js, line 19 :

```
bootstrap: '/js/lib/bootstrap.min',
```

I discovered that the site loads several incompatible versions of Boostrap at the same time, notably 3.3.7 from a CDN and also 2.2.1 locally (via /js/lib/bootstrap.min') via /lib/common.js [and also other old stuff like jQuery 1.7!], and possibly other conflicting libraries. I conclude that since common.js is loaded *after* version 3.3.7 of the CDN, it overrides the latter and that's a bug, because if you launch the homepage just with 3.3.7 there is no bug in fact in the mobile nav: see copden :

https://codepen.io/larrytherabbit/pen/gOrvzbj

Anyway, if you take a look at my codepen, the nav mobile works 100% well. And it's 3.3.7 that is present (I think), which makes me think that the problem is there, or at least partly.

So, if you're going to modify /lib/common.js and remove the old libraries, I think it'll be fine. If it doesn't work, come back to me and I'll take another look.

Comment: Effectivement, simplement commenter out la version local de bootstrap a regle le trouble!

Comment: Amazing, glad I could help!